# JNA unsigned integer by reference gives strange results

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, unsigned, jna, signed

I'm currently trying to access a C API using JNA. But I have a problem with unsigned integer parameters that are being passed by reference.

So here is the C function in question:

```
int EE_DataGetNumberOfSample(DataHandle hData, unsigned int* nSampleOut);
```

In Java I have:

```
public int EE_DataGetNumberOfSample(Pointer hData, ByReference nSampleOut);
```

And here's how I'm using it:

```
IntByReference nSamplesTaken = new IntByReference();

edk.EE_DataGetNumberOfSample(hData.getValue(), nSamplesTaken);

int nativeNSamplesTaken = nSamplesTaken.getValue();

System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(nativeNSamplesTaken)+"("+nativeNSamplesTaken+")");
```

This gives me:

> 11000100110110010011000000(51602624)

Altough it should be 0.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm using the JNA-API?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

There's nothing wrong with the code snippets I posted here, but there was another completely unrelated error that has nothing to do with the question.

[closed]